# Ruby select options if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my db i have 3 fields:

```
name, cost, active
```

How can i display in select (form) only that values, on which active field is true(1)?
Now i have such code:

```
= f.select :shipping_id, [["Select", "0"]] + @shippings.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {:required => true}
```

How to map, only if active is true?

Note! i must done it only in view!

Comment: Some People are just like that mate I have learned that in many occasions. Just do not be discouraged about. However You have to be careful with those minus. If you get too many down vote on your question, stack overflow will stop you from asking questions. I will give +1 for you to lift it of from the minus ;). Have a look at asking [quality question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/), Although I do not see any fault in yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@shippings.select{|s| s.active}.map{|c| [c.name,c.id]}
```

Comment: sorry, what you mean prompt?

Comment: sorry... all is ok, just one mistake

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
@shippings = Shipping.where(:active => 1)
```